# How to architect a Linux application so that it can use a passphrase that is inaccessible to its users?

Tags: linux, unix

The Linux application under consideration is one that will be used by multiple employees of a company, and which, in order to carry out some of its functions, must be able to access a secret passphrase<sup>1</sup> that most regular users of the applications are not authorized to see.

One possibility that comes to mind is to create a special Unix user `foo` (for example), with minimal privileges, make `foo` the owner of both the application's executable and the passphrase file, set the permissions of the passphrase file to 0400 (i.e. accessible only to `foo`, and only for reading), and then set the setuid bit of the application's executable.  In this way, whenever the application runs, it would run as `foo`, and therefore would have read-access to the passphrase file, but this file would still remain inaccessible to any other unprivileged user.

This scheme is only as strong as the security of a standard Unix filesystem.  In particular, anyone with root privileges can access the passphrase file directly.

Now, setuid applications are notoriously difficult to implement properly.

Therefore, I would like to know of other architectures for achieving the same goal, and that may be easier to implement.

(**NB**: even though I have tagged this question with [unix] and [linux], I am not looking for strategies that *depend* on Linux/Unix-specific features, like the setuid feature described above.  All I require of a candidate architecture is that it be easily implementable under Linux.)

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> In case it matters, this passphrase is to be used for symmetric cryptography.</sup>

Comment: Have you considered ACL through things like SELinux? In theory, this could allow a specific application access, without needing the setuid complications.

Comment: Are the users logging into the system using different accounts?  If so, would it be reasonable to add those users to a particular group, and the application and corresponding passphrase file would only be readable by members of that group?

Also, does the solution need to exist on a single system, or can it be spread across multiple system?

Comment: @user52472: I don't want any of the users to be able to read the passphrase file.  (The group idea is still useful though, because I also want to restrict the use of the application to a small set of users.)  The solution would probably exist in a single system, at least for the first few years of operation.